# D7 new form default properties

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I know how to add a form to the Repository in D7 and that I can set its properties to be used as the default for new Main Forms and New Forms by checking the boxes below the form list in the pop-up from Tools->Repository.

That all works fine.  However, if I do **not** check the New Form checkbox in the Tools->Repository pop-up, then if I click File->New->Form, the IDE creates a new form which is excessively wide for my system (clientwidth = 963).  I would like to change this and my question is, where does Delphi get this client width value from?

I've Grep-searched my entire disk for DFM files containing 'clientwidth = 963') but GExperts does not find any.  Also, I can see nothing in the Delphi32.Dro file (under \d7\bin) which explains this.

I have a related question about Seattle, but I'll post that separately because I intend this one to be specifically about D7.

Comment: Interesting.  "where does Delphi get this client width value from?"  You mean, if none of the forms under Tools | Repository has the `New Form` checkbox checked?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I am wondering if it is stored in some kind of template file with a different file extension.

Comment: Is the form not maximized?

Comment: @TheBitman:  No, why do you ask?

Comment: Why the downvote?  I have spent quite a long time trying to find the answer to this q myself.

Comment: Because you did not find any code segment which modifies the width/hight parameters to the screen sizes.

Comment: Nowhere. A new form's size depends on the workarea size.